# How to implement kind of global try..finally in TPL?

Tags: task-parallel-library

I have async method that returns Task. From time to time my process is recycling/restarting. Work is interruping in the middle of the Task. Is there more or less general approach in TPL that I can at least log that Task was interruped?

1. I am hosting in ASP.NET, so I can use IRegisteredObject to cancel tasks  with CancellationToken. I do not like this however. I need to pass CancellationToken in all methods and I have many of them.
2. try..finally in each method does not seem even to raise. ContinueWith also does not work

Any advice?

I have single place I start my async tasks, however each task can have any number of child tasks. To get an idea:

```
class CommandRunner
{
  public Task Execute(object cmd, Func<object, Task> handler)
  {
    return handler(cmd).ContinueWith(t => 
    {
       if (t.State = == TaskStatus.Faulted)
       {
          // Handle faultes, log them
       }
       else if (x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
       {
          // Audit
       }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code? Sample-code and pseudo-code is enough.

Comment: @usr , I added some code

Answer (score 0):

Tasks don't just get "interrupted" somehow. They always get completed, faulted or cancelled. There is no global hook to find out about those completions. So the only option to do your logging is to either instrument the bodies of your tasks or hook up continuations for everything.

Comment: ASP.NET recycle process from time to time. What occures with tasks when process recycling?

Comment: All threads are .Abort()'ed, meaning they see a threadabortexception. Steven Toub explains what happens then: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/parallelextensions/thread/894007ae-d9ea-4803-9ae3-952b66896117

Comment: Main problem that I do not get ThreadAbortedException in ContinueWith. And so cannot handle it.

Comment: Hm sounds plausible because all threads are shutting down. Probably unstarted tasks, and continuations are tasks, are discarded intentionally. Can you wrap your task bodies like this? var newHandler = () => { try { oldHandler(); } catch(ThreadAbortException) { log(); }